# Analog of virtualrails.org for python

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django

Just met such great project - http://virtualrails.org

Wondering are there somethigs similar for python/django development ?

Comment: Would have helped if you briefly described what it does, so we don't have to go and look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turnkey has a large selection of images, including Django: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/django VirtualBox is the easiest way to use these images: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/installation-appliances-virtualbox

Comment: Since it is only one answer throught that time, I accepted. But those turnkey linux, is not exactly analog of virtualrails.org